# Rails Concern when included in ActiveJob not as expected

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activesupport, rails-activejob, activesupport-concern

I'm experiencing some strange behaviour when including a Concern into an ActiveJob class.

This is a scaled back version of the issue I'm having. I'm creating a concern, which uses a `included` block to set `retry_on` and pass it class names set in the individual jobs - I'm using `puts my_method` below to simplify the example.

```rb
module FooConcern
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do
    puts my_method
  end

  def self.my_method
    :foo
  end

  def my_method
    :bar
  end
end

class TestJob < ActiveJob::Base
  include FooConcern

  def self.my_method
    :baz
  end

  def my_method
    :biz
  end

  def perform; end
end
```

Inside the console, I am seeing the following when I try and run `perform_now` or `perform_later`, but as you can see, normal instantiation works as expected:

```
irb(main):001:0> TestJob.perform_now
Traceback (most recent call last):
        5: from (irb):1
        4: from app/jobs/test_job.rb:19:in `<main>'
        3: from app/jobs/test_job.rb:20:in `<class:TestJob>'
        2: from app/jobs/test_job.rb:20:in `include'
        1: from app/jobs/test_job.rb:7:in `block in <module:FooConcern>'
NameError (undefined local variable or method `my_method' for TestJob:Class)
Did you mean?  method

irb(main):002:0> TestJob.my_method
=> :baz

irb(main):003:0> TestJob.new.my_method
=> :biz
```

But, when I move the `include FooConcern` to the end of the class, it all works as I would expect:

```rb
class TestJob < ActiveJob::Base
  def self.my_method
    :baz
  end

  def my_method
    :biz
  end

  def perform; end

  include FooConcern
end
```

```
irb(main):001:0> TestJob.perform_now
baz

Performing TestJob (Job ID: 2239d1e8-d7cb-4a22-ae1d-cfc62bdb802a) from Async(default) enqueued at Performed TestJob (Job ID: 2239d1e8-d7cb-4a22-ae1d-cfc62bdb802a) from Async(default) in 0.08ms
=> nil
```

I also tried putting the methods inside the `included` block:

```rb
module FooConcern
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do
    puts my_method

    def self.my_method
      :foo
    end

    def my_method
      :bar
    end
  end
end

class TestJob < ActiveJob::Base
  include FooConcern

  # ...
end
```

With the same result:

```
irb(main):001:0> TestJob.perform_now
Traceback (most recent call last):
        5: from (irb):1
        4: from app/jobs/test_job.rb:19:in `<main>'
        3: from app/jobs/test_job.rb:20:in `<class:TestJob>'
        2: from app/jobs/test_job.rb:20:in `include'
        1: from app/jobs/test_job.rb:7:in `block in <module:FooConcern>'
NameError (undefined local variable or method `my_method' for TestJob:Class)
```

I tried `prenpend`ing the concern and using a `prepended` block, but saw the same results... when the concern is included at the top of the class it fails, at the bottom of the class it works.

Am I missing something? Is there a way to have access to the TestJob methods inside the `included` block inside the Concern?

Comment: Ruby is a top to bottom, left to right lexical parser. 
When it comes across `include FooConcern` it does as instructed which runs the `Module#included` hook and invokes `append_features`. Since `my_method` is not defined at the point in time where `included` runs (because we haven't seen it yet) it raises a `NameError`. I am a bit unclear on what the expectation is here when calling `puts my_method` (yes I understand it is an example), do you expect this to call `FooConcern::my_method` or `TestJob::my_method`?

Answer (score 0):

This issue occurs because, when you include a concern at the top of a class definition, the concern's included method gets executed before the rest of the class definition is processed, while the rest of the methods of the concern are defined in the context of the including class. So, when you call my_method inside the included method, it first looks for the method in the concern, which doesn't have a definition for it. On the other hand, if you include the concern at the bottom of the class definition, the rest of the class definition gets processed first, so when you call my_method inside the concern, it looks for the method in the class, which does have a definition for it. A way to solve this is to pass the class that includes the concern as a parameter to the included method. You can then use that class to call its methods inside the concern. Here's an updated version of the code:

```
module FooConcern
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do |klass|
    puts klass.my_method
  end
end

class TestJob < ActiveJob::Base
  include FooConcern

  def self.my_method
    :baz
  end

  def my_method
    :biz
  end

  def perform; end
end
```

Now, when you run TestJob.perform_now, you should see :baz printed.

Comment: Have you actually tested this because your implementation will raise the same error.  As per my comment at this line `include FooConcern` the `TestJob::my_method` has yet to be defined so this `klass.my_method` will result in a `NoMethodError`. Your implementation is more explicit than the original post by using the yielded class as the receiver however it is identical in functionality because inside the `included` block `klass == self`. [Example](https://replit.com:/@engineersmnky/Moduleincluded-lexical-parsing)